# how to configure traefik with nginx for cotrrect work with https schema?

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I faced with problem when using nginx with traefik. My project works correctly standalone, with nginx image, but when I try to implemented traefik I faced with some trouble, my SERVER global var did not contains HTTPS key, regarding this laravel did not undertstand it and used for assetic and other stuff which used `\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::formatScheme` - `http` instead `https`. When I try to provided force schema solution, this is resolved problem, but I guess this is not correct way for this case, becasue stand alone everythign works perfect. So this is my nginx in stand alone version which works correct and assets loaded with https schema:

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "../:/var/www"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

with conf

```
server {
    server_name my_project.local.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certificates/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certificates/key.pem;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /storage/ {
        alias /var/www/storage/app/public/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        fastcgi_pass php-img:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php-img_errors.log";
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/php-img_service.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/php-img_service.error.log  crit;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and antother case when I added traefic image

```
  lu-traefik:
    image: traefik:2.4.8
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "4200:4200"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/lu-traefik/dev/traefik.yml
        target: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/lu-traefik/dev/configuration/
        target: /traefik/configuration/
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/lu-traefik/dev/tls
        target: /traefik/tls
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"

  lu-backend-nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.0-alpine
    depends_on:
      - lu-backend-php
      - lu-traefik
    restart: on-failure
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.r-lu-backend-nginx-https.rule=Host(`lu-backend.local.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.r-lu-backend-nginx-https.entrypoints=web-secure
      - traefik.http.routers.r-lu-backend-nginx-https.service=s-lu-backend-nginx-https
      - traefik.http.routers.r-lu-backend-nginx-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.services.s-lu-backend-nginx-https.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./apps/lu-backend
        target: /var/www
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/lu-backend/nginx/lumaly.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/lumaly.conf
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/lu-backend/nginx/lumaly.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/sites-enable/lumaly.conf
```

and lumaly.conf

```
server {
    server_name lu-backend.local.com;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /storage/ {
        alias /var/www/storage/app/public/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        fastcgi_pass lu-backend-php:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php-lumaly_errors.log";
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/php-lumaly_service.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/php-lumaly_service.error.log  crit;


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and when I try to open https://lu-backend.local.com I faced with project page, but assets (css and js files) did not loaded, becuase by some reason they try to loaded by http schema, which can not be loaded

if I addded to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $current = \URL::current();
//        if(config('app.env') === 'local') {
//            \URL::forceScheme('https');
//        }
    }
```

I faced with http schema, becuase SERVER var did not contains HTTPS key.

`\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isSecure`:

```
$https = $this->server->get('HTTPS'); // return null
return !empty($https) && 'off' !== strtolower($https);
```

there is what returned docker compose ps

```
lu_lu-backend-mariadb_1_807f9a7f6096   docker-entrypoint.sh --def ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8306->3306/tcp                     
lu_lu-backend-nginx_1_b2df3bd1ddc1     /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      80/tcp                                     
lu_lu-backend-php_1_566405992c8f       bash /usr/local/bin/docker ...   Up      9000/tcp                                   
lu_lu-redis_1_12cc7e7d897e             docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                     
lu_lu-traefik_1_78171c03c3d5           /entrypoint.sh traefik           Up      0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp,                    
                                                                                0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,  
                                                                                0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

So, my question how to configure treafic with nginx for cotrrect work with https schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your whole setup, but you don't need to expose port 80 from your nginx container.

Maybe just try to remove

```
expose:
      - "80"
```

Comment: I try to changed it to 433 and it's not help

Comment: I didn't mean to change it to 443, but remove it entirely. You are using traefik as a reverse proxy, so traefik is the only container that should expose ports.